# Delay ON circuit to turn off LEDs

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, delay

I'm using STM32L432KBU6 to drive AQW214EHAX Solid State Relay to turn some other circuit ON when it is needed for up to 300ms. Circuit I'm using below:
[image: Base circuit]

I would like to add some kind of safety circuitry that would turn LEDs OFF when MCU_PIN is HIGH for more than 1 second.

Can anyone help me with such circuit? I cannot make anything transistor-based to not leak a tiniest amount of current when in OFF state with MCU_PIN HIGH.

**@EDIT1**

I have figured some circuit. What do you think about it?
R5, R7, R8 and Q2 allows for fast capacitor discharge when MCU_PIN is pulled low. I have decided to go with PMOS / PNP because of available space near MCU - I can squeze that parts there, but not much space near SSR.
[image: Circuit]

Comment: Would be simpler to implement this on the MCU or do you have safety concerns? From what I understand, you have 700ms margin, more than enough time for a watchdog to kick in an reset the MCU in case there is a bug. Alternatively you could use a 555 to generate 300ms (or 1s) pulses and cancel its output after a desired time with the MCU (e.g. by shorting the SSRs inputs with nMOSFETs). This way, pulses will never be longer than 300ms (or 1s) in case the MCU fails somehow.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I already have that implemented in code, that allows for additional 100ms above set time. No reset with watchdog though. Now I'm looking for second line of defence using physical components. Please check updated post for something I came up with.